# Returning data via Sage API always results in unauthorised

Tags: php, sage-erp

I'm using the following code to try to return data for our warehouses via the Sage API. We're using Sage 200 standard (docs [here](https://developer.columbus.sage.com/docs#/uk/sage200/accounts)). Every time I try to run the script it takes me to a 404 with an unauthorised error.

The annoying thing is that if I use all the same details in Postman then it works. The only difference being is that the callback url is https://id.sage.com/mobile and when I send the data, it brings up a popup to login. Once I login and get the access token everything works.

I just want to recreate that process but via a webpage but no matter how I structure the code I don't get the same popup and everything just falls apart after it.

Where am I going wrong? Any help much appreciated.

```
$clientId = 'XXX';
$clientSecret = 'XXX';
$redirectUri = 'https://example.com/sage-stock/';

if (!isset($_GET['code'])) {
    // If the 'code' parameter is not in the URL, start the authorization process
    $authUrl = 'https://id.sage.com/authorize?';
    $authUrl .= 'response_type=code';
    $authUrl .= '&client_id=' . $clientId;
    $authUrl .= '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($redirectUri);
    $authUrl .= '&scope=openid%20profile%20email%20offline_access';
    $authUrl .= '&audience=s200ukipd/sage200';
    $authUrl .= '&state=1235';

    header('Location: ' . $authUrl);
    exit;
} else {
    // If the 'code' parameter is in the URL, exchange it for an access token
    $code = $_GET['code'];

    $tokenUrl = 'https://id.sage.com/oauth/token';
    $postData = [
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        'client_id' => $clientId,
        'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
        'code' => $code,
        'redirect_uri' => $redirectUri
    ];

    $ch = curl_init($tokenUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postData));

    $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
    curl_close($ch);

    $accessToken = $response['access_token'];
    $refreshToken = $response['refresh_token'];

    // Use the access token to make a request to the Sage API
    $headers = [
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accessToken,
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'ocp-apim-subscription-key: XXX',
        'X-Site: XXX',
        'X-Company: XXX'
    ];

    $apiUrl = 'https://api.columbus.sage.com/uk/sage200/accounts/v1/warehouses/';

    $ch = curl_init($apiUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
    curl_close($ch);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($response);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```